# How to use CDN's for Google Chrome Extension and not violate the Content Security Policy directive?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, cdn

I am Working on a Google Chrome extension. In one of the files, the HTML calls an external script through CDN. I know that I need to mention the same in the manifest to not violate Content Security Policy. After going through some previous questions related to the same topic, I found out the answers are not working out for me and I have no clue why? Also, I would like to mention that I am working on the new **manifest version 3**.

This is the CDN I am calling from the HTML File:-

```
 <script src="https://ajaxorg.github.io/ace-builds/src-min-noconflict/ace.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Below is the code I wrote in the manifest.json for permission:-

```
    "content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'; script-src-elem 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://ajaxorg.github.io/;"
},
```

Below is the error I am getting in the console window:-

[Error Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2fWd.png)

I am a complete beginner working on extension, so it would be very much helpful, If someone guide me out. Thanks in Advance !!!

Comment: You can't use remote scripts in MV3. Download the script and load it like you load your own scripts.

Comment: Well the problem with that option is that I am using the ace editor and it, in turn, uses a lot of build files. I already tried that option first, but it didn't load some scripts like to change themes etc.

Comment: You'll have to include all of them locally.